# Adjust brakes in 2005 Lexus rx 330 as a DIY?

Tags: brakes, lexus

Can I adjust the brakes? what tools are needed? Is it a big job?

Comment: service brake or park brake?

Comment: @mike service brakes

Comment: Your vehicle seems to have front and rear disc brakes. Can you describe what issues you are having?

Answer (score 1):

The Lexus RX 330 have self-adjusting disc brakes all round. They are servo assisted and are adjusted simply by pressing the brake pedal a couple of times to prime the system. Some drivers do not realise the servo effect and may think they have a problem. Do this to determine the servo operation: With the engine turned off, pump the brake pedal until you have a solid pedal- no more than six pumpms should do this. Now pressing on the brake pedal, car in neutral, start the engine. You will feel the brake pedal sink down. This is the servo operating correctly. If you do have any concerns though with your brakes you should have them checked out by a mechanic.